# Referencing custom view in XML doesn´t work both documented ways?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

```
<com.test.www.BrushPreview android:id="@+id/brushview"
    android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

and this not:

```
<View class="com.test.www.BrushPreview" android:id="@+id/brushview"
    android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Following the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying it should work both ways! What am I doing wrong?

edit:
lowercase view seems to work! i thought i tried that already...thanks! 
and furthermore, it´s very important to use this constructor in the view class:

```
public BrushPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

otherwise it won´t get called.

Comment: What happens? An exception? It just doesn't appear?

Comment: you have any class file related this path com.test.www.BrushPreview..?

Comment: @CapDroid I wanna believe he does, since he says the 1st method works OK

Comment: no exceptions whatsoever, the view just isn´t drawn and no constructor is called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use lowercase `view` in the xml for your custom layout:

```
<view class="com.test.www.BrushPreview" android:id="@+id/brushview"
    android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

(according to [your link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying) too), and it should work.

Otherwise it tries to create a `android.view.View` instance.